# Storing location tracking data

Tags: database

I am working on a project that requires me to store the history of a GPS device that sends its location every second. 
The application has to save and ultimately show the tracked route while the GPS device is active.

My main concern is saving all this data. Having multiple devices and saving all their positions throughout time seems like a difficult task.

How would I go about storing and retrieving the locations. Storing all this in a database doesn't sound logical to me. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you start by putting `[database] gps` in that search box at the top of this page.

Comment: `Storing all this in a database doesn't sound logical to me.` Why not? Databases can scale to accommodate huge amounts of data. You'd track the latitude and longitude as floats.  How many devices are anticipated?

Comment: The search was great. Lots of valuable resources. Thanks. 
@Tim Whats more important here is that I cannot flush the data in my database from time to time to lighten the load.
I have to keep all of my saved locations indefinitely.
More so, I was wondering if I have other alternatives to storing floats in my database.

Comment: Also, data in the aggregate has value.

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm also working with realtime location data. But the problem is if we store that longitude and latitude  every 10 seconds, then the table will fill with millions of records. It's become very heavy by increasing of the number of users. If there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 5):

It would make sense to only store a location if it's changed wrt the previous measurement. GPS devices are not on the move constantly after all.

You'd also have to think about things as:

- how long will I store this data for? so can i recycle data spots?
- if i only store changes, should i store a delta (not recommended) or an actual position?
- how do i store the position in the least amount of space, whilst still being able to use the data to effictively calculate travelling paths (if need be), draw maps and what not

Basically - you'd have to look at all the requirements that this data will be used for, before stomping it all in a box...

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a requirement to create reports on this routing data? If yes then have to persist data.

I can think of a couple of options to save this data.

1. Using [Cache blocks from Ms. Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953179%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx)
2. NoSQL databases

NoSQL databases like [db40.](http://www.db4o.com/) Key/Value Storage more appropriate to use here.

3. Lightweight database.
   [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [Google's LevelDB.](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/)

Frequency - Initially I will opt-in to store this data for every half mile. i.e to calculate the distance between first recorded location to the second location

Comment: Yes, I have to create multiple reports such as speed control and limitations, moving and stopping times, checking distance to specific locations etc.
Thanks, I will look into these technologies.

Answer (score 1):

I's very important to know the requirements!

In general storing the data in a database sounds OK to me. Wether a relational database or a no SQl database is the better solution depends on your requirements.

Databases are designed to store and retrieve millions of recods. Maybe you are able to use partitioning in your database. If you are able to partition your data by time, then your old data won't hurt actions on partitions with actual data.

Answer (score 0):

I think dynamodb can fit in. It is an amazon service mainly for heavy read and write operations.